# Daily Cron job not executing

Tags: bash, permissions, backup, cron

I created the following cron job under `/etc/cron.daily/backup-vivashost`

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

mkdir /var/lib/html-backup/www-$DATE/
cp -R /var/www/html/* /var/lib/backups/html-backup/www-$DATE/
find /var/lib/bakcups/html-backup/* -type f -mtime +5 -delete
```

One day after i created this there is no copy of `/var/www/html/` to `/var/lib/backups/html-backup/`

Is it because the shell is not runing under `sudo su` root permissions or ?

Can you please tell me a reason why it is not working ?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `cron.daily`, not `daily.cron`.

Comment: It's typo. The correct one is like you mentioned.

Comment: Did the `www-$DATE` directory get created?

Comment: And you're sure, that the modification time is changed with your `cp` command? Run the job again without the deletion and check it.

Comment: No.. Even the directory is not created!

Comment: I do not know how to run the cronjob. When i type `crontab -e` i get `602` and thats all..

Comment: Mind you there may be another typo, the new directory is created in `/var/lib/html-backup/` but you expect the copy to go to `/var/lib/backups/html-backup/`.

Comment: How can i execute this cronjob now ?

Comment: To preserve the timestamps use `cp -pR`

Comment: Test in a stand-alone shell script first to see if it works (e.g. make a file called `script.sh` and run that). Then you can tune it to fix any errors and make it work as desired. I would recommend commenting out the find command for initial tests though, then check how the times compare in `ls -l`  or `stat`.

Comment: `crontab -e` should open your default command line editor with the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/[user]`. So either there is something wrong with that file, or with your default editor.

Comment: And don't use the astrix in your find command

Comment: And with `type -f`, only comes will be deleted and no folders. Is it that what you need, I don't think so.

Comment: and don't search for "bakcups"  if you meant "backups"

Comment: Next thing, is the script execuable?

Comment: And there is another typo in the path of your find command

Comment: When i execute this script i get: `bash: ./vivashost.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: Can anyone make complete answer editing my mistakes ?

Comment: @TonyStark I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

First, correct the path names in the script file `/etc/cron.daily/backupvivashost` and apply A.B's suggestions:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir /var/lib/backups/html-backup/www-$DATE/
cp -pR /var/www/html/* /var/lib/backups/html-backup/www-$DATE/ 
find /var/lib/backups/html-backup -mtime +5 -delete
```

Then, make the file executable:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/backupvivashost`

Then execute the file to see if it works:

`sudo /etc/cron.daily/backupvivashost`

If it works, see if it will also run when called by crontab. The script needs `sudo` privileges so it should be called by the root crontab.

`sudo crontab -e`

will do that. If that doesn't work, there is something wrong with the default editor, or with the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. To specify `nano` as your editor, do

`export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano`

When you manage to open the crontab with the editor, enter dates and times to have your script executed. If you want to run it at 17:00, enter:

`0 17 * * * /etc/cron.daily/backupvivashost > /home/user/logfile 2>&1`

This way, you will get to see what goes wrong in the file `/home/user/logfile`. When that works as well, remove the line from the crontab, as the script will now be run daily anyway.

Comment: When i do `sudo crontab -e` i get output on the next row `602` and that's all. I have to close the terminal and open it again to start typing any kind of commands. It is so weird...

Comment: Move the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` out of the way, or delete it if you are sure it doesn't contain any useful information. Then try `sudo crontab -e` again.

Comment: It contains the following information: http://pastebin.com/JmYywPRU . It is important to be there. Can i add another line so i can make this cron job executable in a specific hour every day ?

Comment: No, you can't simply edit that file. What crontab does is: it lets you edit the file, then after you save it, it processes its contents. There is no other way to do the latter part. Anyway as it is a valid crontab file, the error must be that your default editor is not called.

Comment: About the not-functioning of your `crontab -e` command and the "602" line that results, may I ask you to post a separate question on this site? When that is solved, this answer here should be more or less complete. I have a couple of things you could try.

Comment: So at the last line i can add `0 17 * * * /etc/cron.daily/backupvivashost > /home/user/logfile 2>&1` and will make my cron job work at 17:00 every day ?

Comment: Yes, provided you do that via `crontab -e` and not through straight editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31197/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-jos).

Comment: can we continue that with chat ?

Comment: I'm on the chat page right now. I have about 15 mins. If you can't reach me, find my email address on my web site and we'll sort something out.